# Can a custom UserNamePasswordValidator add things to the WCF session?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554849/with-custom-usernamepasswordvalidator-can-i-kill-the-users-wpf-session), I'm instantiating a connection to our internal API inside my custom UserNamePasswordValidator. Can I stash this somewhere so that I can use it in future calls in that user's session?

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317000/access-the-current-instancecontext-in-a-wcf-usernamepasswordvalidator), but I'm not using IIS, so I can't use HttpContext.Current (or can I?).

**Update:** Some context: our internal API is exposed via a COM object, which exposes a `Login` method. Rather than have a `Login` method in my service interface, I've got a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator`, which calls the Login method on the COM object.

Because instantiating the COM object and logging in is expensive, I'd like to re-use the now-logged-in COM object in my service methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can. You'll need:

- a custom `ServiceCredentials` implementation that returns a custom `SecurityTokenManager`.
- a custom `SecurityTokenManager` implementation that returns a custom `CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator`.
- your custom `CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator` needs to override `ValidateUserNamePasswordCore`, and should add a custom implementation of `IAuthorizationPolicy`.
- your implementation of `IAuthorizationPolicy` should implement `Evaluate`, at which point it can start putting things in the WCF context.
- replace the `evaluationContext["PrimaryIdentity"]` value with a `PasswordIdentity` or a custom `IIdentity`.
- replace the `evaluationContext["Principal"]` value with a `PasswordPrincipal` or a custom `IPrincipal`.
- update the `evaluationContext["Identities"]` collection to replace the `GenericIdentity` instance with your custom instance.

By doing this, you can have a custom `IPrincipal` implementation with some extra information in it.

For more details, see [this](http://www.neovolve.com/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user/).

Answer (score 0):

UserNamePasswordValidator is absolutely out of all WCF contexts. It is only used to validate user name and password. Can you futher explain your problem?

**Edit:**
I guess COM object is instantiated for each session, isn't it? Otherwise wrapping COM into singleton should solve your problem. If you need to have per session COM object shared between validator and service instance you will need some cache or registry - something which is outside both validator and service and can be called from both of them.

Comment: To validate the user name and password, I have to instantiate an expensive COM object. Since I'll be using it later, I'd like to associate it with the session.