# Can a custom UserNamePasswordValidator be used as a role provider?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554868/can-a-custom-usernamepasswordvalidator-add-things-to-the-wcf-session), I've got a custom UserNamePasswordValidator that logs in to our internal API. As part of this logging-in, I can discover the user's roles in our system.

I'd like to later use these in PrincipalPermissionAttribute demands on the service methods, e.g.:

```
[OperationContract]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "System Administrator")]
public string HelloWorld()
{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Roger, have you managed to solve this problem? I'd like to do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on Ladislav's answer:

No. A custom UserNamePasswordValidator cannot be used as a role provider. The UserNamePasswordValidator runs in a separate context (or thread, or something) from the OperationContext that you want to mess with.

What you need to do instead is implement custom authorization. I found [this page](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx) most useful for doing this. Warning: there's a lot of plumbing before you get to the interesting bits.

Essentially, you start with a `ServiceCredentials`-derived class, registered in `App.config`, as follows:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="...">
    <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" />

    <serviceCredentials type="MyNamespace.MyServiceCredentials, MyAssembly">
      <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" />

      <serviceCertificate etc. />
    </serviceCredentials>
```

Associate the behavior with your service.

Override `ServiceCredentials.CreateSecurityTokenManager` to return a `MySecurityTokenManager`, derived from `ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager`. On that, override `CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator`, returning a `MySecurityTokenAuthenticator`. That should be derived from `CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator`. In that, override `ValidateUserNamePasswordCore`. Call the base class, which will return a list of authorization policies.

To that list, add a new one: `MyAuthorizationPolicy`, which implements `IAuthorizationPolicy`. In that, you merely (hah) need to do the following:

```
public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
{
    IList<IIdentity> identities = GetIdentities(evaluationContext);

    // Find the GenericIdentity with our user-name in it.
    IIdentity currentIdentity = identities.SingleOrDefault(
        i => i is GenericIdentity &&
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(i.Name, UserName));
    if (currentIdentity == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No Identity found");

    // Replace the GenericIdentity with a new one.
    identities.Remove(currentIdentity);
    var newIdentity =
        new GenericIdentity(_userName, currentIdentity.AuthenticationType);
    identities.Add(newIdentity);

    // This makes it available as
    // ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity later.
    evaluationContext.Properties["PrimaryIdentity"] = newIdentity;

    // This makes it available as Thread.CurrentPrincipal.
    IPrincipal newPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(newIdentity, _roles);
    evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = newPrincipal;

    return true;
}

private static IList<IIdentity> GetIdentities(
    EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
{
    object identitiesProperty;
    if (!evaluationContext.Properties.TryGetValue(
        "Identities", out identitiesProperty))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No Identity found");

    var identities = identitiesProperty as IList<IIdentity>;
    if (identities == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No Identity found");
    return identities;
}
```

And then, having done that lot, you can mark up your service operations with `PrincipalPermission`:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Editor")]
```

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584198/authentication-service-using-wcf ?

Comment: @Lijo No, because the two are unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can't because you need to create custom Principal. The reason why I think you can't do it in the validator is because I read somewhere that the validator runs in different thread than operation context. I have never checked it but lets assume it really does. Based on this assumption Principal set in the validator will not be used in WCF operation. You have to create [custom autorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731181.aspx) or custom role provider.